# Why is STM32 (STM32H7A3ZITxQ) 12-bit ADC minimal readout around 60 instead of 0?

Tags: stm32, adc, encoder

I'm trying to read the analog output of an [MT6701](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109011830_Magn-Tek-MT6701CT-STD_C2856764.pdf) magnetic encoder, but I'm having some issues with my ADCs.

The MT6701 provides an analog output where 0 - 3.3 V (I'm using 3.3 V as VDD) represents the absolute angle between 0 and 360 degrees (please see the attached screenshot), but when I read the pin with my STM32's ADCs, a 12-bit, single-ended ADC outputs about 60 for 0° (I was able to verify the angle data by the I2C readout from the encoder), and on the other end, the ADC saturates at 4095 when the angle is about 356°.

Additionally, I verified the output range of this analog pin with my oscilloscope, and it does indeed go from 0 to 3.3 V (with very small errors).

I even plugged a ground pin from the STM32 directly into the ADC pin, and I'm still getting about 60, so it seems for some reason my ADC cannot go below that.

I tried this with multiple ADCs and both regular and injected channels on multiple Nucleo boards, and I got the same result.

Can someone please help me understand why this is?

[image]

Comment: Could be a sampling issue, try adjusting clock rate / prescaler, or other timing parameters? Is the system noisy? Coherent EMI might read as a fixed error. Note also, the ADC reads relative to AGND which might not be exactly what you're probing against; and verify that your meter reads low voltages accurately.

Comment: First thing that crosses my mind is uncompensated offset. And once the offset is compensated for, I'd figure on noticing some uncompensated gain -- maybe even varying gain over the range.

Comment: I think you need to separate the problem into several pieces (the 'lysis' in analysis). Read the RAW ADC value in the STM32 (no calculations just look at the HEX value), and apply ONLY a DC voltage from a potentiometer across the supply rails to the ADC input. Use a DVM to measure the input voltage, not an oscilloscope.

Comment: Is the encoder on the same PCB as the STM32? Do you have a solid(ish) ground plane or at the very least some generously wide ground traces supplying power to and between the STM32 and the encoder? A reading of 60 requires less than 50mV between the 2 devices and if there's some current flowing through a small trace which connects GND between the 2 devices, that might 'lift' the encoder's output a little.

Comment: I took @jonk's advice and ran `HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start` and it made things much better -- now for zero V I got 16 rather than 60+, and the saturation at the other end also reduced -- now the ADC saturates (reaches 4095) when the encoder reports 357 degrees. So it does seem to be an offset issue. I'm trying to find a way to do a better job than HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start. Thanks!

Comment: @RoyLi I've been through this so many times in my life I can't even begin to count them. You usually want to find a "quiet time" to run a burst of ADC readings, averaging them, in order to get a bead on the offset you face. This gets saved somewhere. But you must update it frequently as temperature and time affect it. It's never the same, twice. If you care about gain (and you should), then you need a reference source that will provide you a voltage ramp (or your MT6701 if you trust it) and you record values over the ADC range to calibrate gain over the range.

Comment: @RoyLi The basic problem is that that the universe isn't perfect and ADCs also aren't perfect. And the circuit leading up to the ADC input *also* isn't perfect. And beyond that, it may take time to "sample" the signal. If you don't allow enough time, then it won't settle and your ADC will read a value that is "on the way, but not quite there yet." Which isn't helpful, either. Mostly, I do my own calibration code. I don't allow anyone to control that. Which means I will NOT use a library for this purpose -- not ever.

Comment: @RoyLi Besides all that? Your MT6701 ***also*** isn't perfect. The key here is to realize that that you have a way of measuring stuff, but the measurements are highly imperfect. And to correct them, you need algorithms and you need data to feed those algorithms so that you can wind up with, after all corrections are said and done, values that are meaningful to your application. This whole process is perhaps one of the more critical steps in generating high quality output values that you can then feed into other algorithms that assume linearity and an offset of zero.

Comment: @RoyLi Take all of this VERY SERIOUSLY. Most of the problems, failures really, that occur are because enough time wasn't spend on characterizing the transducers, the amplifier stages, and the ADC --- all of which feed the rest of the code. And the same happens for the output side. You have a DAC and it drives a circuit, and ... well, the whole thing all over again. Getting the input transducer system and the output transducer system worked out, in detail, is almost ALL of the problem. The rest is just simple math. Focus on INPUT and OUTPUT. Once those are square, the rest will just follow.

Comment: Real ADCs have offset errors, and it's not uncommon to see a few counts when reading out a "zero" input. It's not a concern. You'd calibrate it out during system calibration/commissioning. And you will most definitely need both an offset and gain calibration in this system. I.e. you'll need to measure the ADC value of a "zero" as well as "full scale", and use those to map the raw ADC readouts into physical units.